# Determining when to try an IPv6 connection and when to use IPv4

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm working on a network client program that connects to public servers, specified by the user.  If the user gives me a hostname to connect to that has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses (commonly, a DNS name with both `A` and `AAAA` records), I'm not sure how I should decide which address I should connect to.

The problem is that it's quite common for machines to support both IPv4 and IPv6, but only to have global connectivity over IPv4.  The most common case of this is when only IPv6 link-local addresses are configured.  At the moment the best alternatives I can come up with are:

1. Try the IPv6 address(es) first - if the connection fails, try the IPv4 address(es); or
2. Just let the user specify it as a config setting ("prefer_ipv6" versus "prefer_ipv4").

The problem I can see with option 1 is that the connection might not fail straight away - it might take quite a while to time out.

Comment: What advantages do you expect from using IPv6 instead of IPv4 ?

Comment: That's really a question for the users - but if they've gone to the trouble to join the public IPv6 internet I'll assume they have their reasons.

Comment: When I was experimenting with the prototype code for http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-wing-http-new-tech-00 (I did only IPv4/IPv6 part, not the SCTP) - the "correct" protocol eventually got autotuned pretty fast. Of course, at the expense of some extra traffic in the beginning.

Comment: Here are the slides for an IETF talk on this subject and the best solution: http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/79/slides/nbs-8.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please do try IPv6. In the significant majority of installations, trying to create an IPv6 connection *will* fail right away if it can't succeed for some reason:

- if the system doesn't support IPv6 sockets, creating the socket will fail
- if the system does support IPv6, and has link-local addresses configured, there won't be any routing table entry for the global IPv6 addresses. Again, the local kernel will report failure without sending any packets.
- if the system does have a global IP address, but some link necessary for routing is missing, the source *should* be getting an ICMPv6 error message, indicating that the destination cannot be reached; likewise if the destination has an IPv6 address, but the service isn't listening on it.

There are of course cases where things can break, e.g. if a global (or tunnel) address is configured, and something falsely filters out ICMPv6 error messages. You shouldn't worry about this case - it may be just as well that IPv4 connectivity is somehow broken.

Of course, it's debatable whether you really need to try the IPv6 addresses **first** - you might just as well try them second. In general, you should try addresses in the order in which they are returned from getaddrinfo. Today, systems support configuration options that let administators decide in what order addresses should be returned from getaddrinfo.

Comment: +1 Examples of "configuration options" are gai.conf on Linux and ip6addrctrl.conf on FreeBSD.

Comment: I'm going to run with this.  (Although I do need to decide the order to try addresses, because I'm using an asynchronous resolver library rather than the blocking `getaddrinfo()` - that's still good advice for those who are using the latter though).

Comment: Martin, I would say the developer *should* worry about the case of blackholed IPv6 :-) - take a look at http://lists.cluenet.de/pipermail/ipv6-ops/2009-November/002658.html and the threads around. At present, it is a real-world problem. And given the setup (typically the ones who implement IPv6 are server sites, and the ones that are broken are the eyeball networks), it creates a catch22 for the migration. (Unlike the TCP widespread window scaling brokennes a couple of years ago). Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @Andrew: Notice that this is a different problem. As Tore reports, the majority of problems is caused by Opera, which (apparently) doesn't implement fallback to IPv4 properly. There are then additional failures - however, there are also other web browsers which show the same flaw. There are then also misconfigurations in the IPv6 net causing such problems; those get likely fixed as people run into them. So activating a dual-stack webserver indeed needs to be considered carefully. If you write TCP clients, I stand by my recommendation to use the OS configuration.

Comment: @Martin: I did not disagree with the idea of using the OS configuration as much as possible. Just that the blackholes are real and sometimes could be not very trivial to fix. But depends on deployment model. Still given that there are two ways to establish connection, in some environments (home PCs? there is frequently no administrator) it might be useful to have some additional robustness at the application level - for the user experience, not technical reasons. Purely technically I am 200% with you - "the broken" should be noticeable so it gets fixed.

Comment: This answer is now outdated. The answer by @Steve-o points to RFC6555 which has an updated recommendation.

Answer (score 6):

Subsequent to the question being asked the IETF has proposed an answer to this question with [RFC6555](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6555), a.k.a. [Happy Eyeballs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Eyeballs).

The pertinent point being the client and server may both have IPv4 and IPv6 but a hop in between may not so it is impossible to reliably predict which path will work.

Answer (score 2):

You should *let the system-wide configuration decide* thanks to `getaddrinfo()`. Just like Java does. Asking every single application to try to cater for every single possible IPv6 (mis)configuration is really not scalable! In case of a misconfiguration it is much more intuitive to the user if *all or none* applications break.

On the other hand you want to try to **log** annoying delays and time-outs profusely, so users can quickly identify what to blame. Just like every other delays ideally, including (very common) DNS time-outs.

Comment: By the way trying to cater for every possible IPv6 misconfiguration is exactly what Opera tried to do. In the end the only thing they made is the top of the IPv6 hall of shame. Too bad because it is a nice browser otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/79/slides/nbs-8.pdf) talk has the solution. To summarize;

- Sometimes there are problems with either DNS lookups or the subsequent connection to the resolved address
- You don't want to wait for connecting to an IPv6 address to timeout before connecting to the IPv4 address, or vice versa
- You don't want to wait for a lookup for an AAAA record to timeout before looking for an A record or vice versa
- You don't want to stall while waiting for both AAAA and A records before attempting to connect with whichever record you get back first.

The solution is to lookup AAAA and A records simultaneously and independently, and to connect independently to the resolved addresses. Use whatever connection succeeds first.

---

The easiest way to do this is to allow the networking API do it for you using connect-by-name networking APIs. For example, in Java:

```
InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("www.example.com", 80);
SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open(socketAddress);
channel.write(buffer);
```

The slide notes say at this point:

> Here we make an opaque object called an InetSocketAddress from a host
>   and port, and then  when we open that SocketChannel, that can complete
>   under the covers, doing whatever is  necessary, without the
>   application ever seeing an IP address.
>
> Windows also has connect-by-name APIs. I don’t have code fragments for
>   those here.
>
> Now, I’m not saying that all implementations of these APIs necessarily
>   do the right thing  today, but if applications are using these APIs,
>   then the implementations can be improved  over time.
>
> The di!erence with getaddrinfo() and similar APIs is that they
>   fundamentally can’t be  improved over time. The API deﬁnition is that
>   they return you a full list of addresses, so they  have to wait until
>   they have that full list to give you. There’s no way getaddrinfo can
>   return  you a partial list and then later give you some more.

Answer (score -3):

Some ideas:

1. Allow the user to specify the preference on a per-site basis.
2. Try IPv4 first.
3. Attempt IPv6 in parallel upon the first connection.
4. On subsequent connections, use IPv6 if the connection was successful previously.

I say to try IPv4 first because that is the protocol which is better established and tested.